# Get child object's rotation for use in RotateTowards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, transform, virtual-reality

I'm creating a 'steady cam' like object in VR that the player can grab and point like they are operating a real video camera.

The prop camera contains an empty **GameObject** called *CameraTarget* where it's lens would be, and using a script (Udon as this is within *VRChat*) I monitor for a notable change in location (to avoid jitter from unsteady hands) and if so, I use `Vector3.MoveTowards()` to smoothly translate the location of another object called *CameraActual* on which is attached a Camera, and then `Quaternion.RotateTowards()` to do the same with the angle.

However, the latter doesn't seem to do anything because as far as I can tell, the *CameraTarget*'s object never changes its rotation angle, even as the prop its attached to is clearly being rotated in space. The value of the `RotateTowards()` operations is always the same even as I swing the camera around. I also tried using *CameraTarget*'s parent object (the camera 3D prop) but that also seemed to not change its value. I can visually confirm this both from the image captured by the camera and as *CameraActual* has an in world visualisation and it remains visually locked in its starting orientation.

How do I get the real camera to point in the same direction it's in game representation is pointing?

Object layout:

- Root

  - CameraPropRoot

    - [CameraMeshes]
    - CameraTarget (Empty GameObject)
  - CameraActualRoot

    - UnityCamera

Pseudo Code of Udon Graph:

```
speed = 3;

Update() {
    var distance = Vector3.Distance(
        ActualCamera.Transform.Position,
        CameraTarget.Transform.Position);
    if (distance > 0.05) {
        var newPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(
            ActualCamera.Transform.Position,
            CameraTarget.Transform.Position,
            speed * Time.deltaTime);

        ActualCamera.Transform.Position = newPosition;
    }

    // Todo: ... Code here to check rotation difference
    var newRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(
        ActualCamera.Transform.rotation,
        CameraTarget.Transform.Rotation,
        speed * Time.deltaTime);
    ActualCamera.Transform.rotation = newRotation;
}
```

Comment: What code are you currently using (especially, which `RotateTowards` are you using and how) and how are you calculating the parameters you're using? The question mentions that the cameraTarget's position is where the camera should be, but is it also oriented how the camera should be? If so, why not `cameraActual.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(cameraActual.transform.rotation, cameraTarget.transform.rotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);` If not, more info is needed especially about the second parameter to `RotateTowards` you are using.

Comment: To shorten @Ruzihm 's comment a bit: Please add your current code and Hierarchy structure ;) And describe how exactly the behavior should look like vs what is happening instead

Comment: I'll need to install the UdonSharp plugin first because VRC doesn't allow raw C# code in its worlds for obvious reasons so you have to code with a visual node graph which is painful. I'll convert it to text code first and then rework my question.

Comment: I have a solution to the problem, it was actually related to the speed not being significant enough due to the different scales of transform and rotation. If reopened I will add the full solution and also the code to show how to calculate the rotation difference.

Comment: @derHugo I'm voting to reopen

Comment: @Ruzihm agreed, go for it ;)

Comment: @Nidonocu It's reopened, btw